# Add empty buckets in mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following aggregation:

```
const buckets = await StatisticModel.aggregate([
  {
    $bucket: {
      groupBy: '$ranking',
      boundaries: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11],
    },
  },
])
```

Which returns the following object:

```
[
  { _id: 3, count: 6  },
  { _id: 4, count: 98 },
  { _id: 5, count: 81 },
  { _id: 6, count: 25 },
  { _id: 7, count: 4 }
]
```

How can I add the missing (empty) buckets?

This is a simple example but I have more complexe ones where I generate the boundaries and I want to return to the front-end all the buckets and not only the filled ones.

Comment: I would fill in blanks on the backend after the mongo query but before the front end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "data": [
      { "$bucket": {
        "groupBy": "$ranking",
        "boundaries": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]
      }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "data": {
      "$map": {
        "input": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11],
        "as": "i",
        "in": {
          "_id": "$$i",
          "count": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [{ "$indexOfArray": ["$data._id", "$$i"] }, -1] },
              0,
              { "$arrayElemAt": ["$data.count", { "$indexOfArray": ["$data._id", "$$i"] }] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" }}
])
```

But better to do with javascript

```
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]
const array2 = [
  { "_id": 3, "count": 6 },
  { "_id": 4, "count": 98 },
  { "_id": 5, "count": 81 },
  { "_id": 6, "count": 25 },
  { "_id": 7, "count": 4 }
]

array.map((ar) => {
  const index = array2.map((e) => { return e._id }).indexOf(ar)
  if (index === -1) {
    array2.push({ _id: ar, count: 0 })
  }
})

console.log(array2)
```

Comment: Thanks, that what I initially thought, I need to do it in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Starting in `Mongo 5.1`, it's a perfect use case for the new [`$densify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/densify/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-densify) aggregation operator:

```
// { ranking: 3, count: 6 }
// { ranking: 4, count: 98 }
// { ranking: 6, count: 25 }
// { ranking: 7, count: 4 }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $densify: {
    field: "ranking",
    range: { step: 1, bounds: [0, 12] }
  }},
  { $set: { count: { $cond: [ { $not: ["$count"] }, 0, "$count" ] } } }
])
// { ranking: 0,  count: 0 } <=
// { ranking: 1,  count: 0 } <=
// { ranking: 2,  count: 0 } <=
// { ranking: 3,  count: 6 }
// { ranking: 4,  count: 98 }
// { ranking: 5,  count: 0 } <=
// { ranking: 6,  count: 25 }
// { ranking: 7,  count: 4 }
// { ranking: 8,  count: 0 } <=
// { ranking: 9,  count: 0 } <=
// { ranking: 10, count: 0 } <=
// { ranking: 11, count: 0 } <=
```

---

This:

- densifies documents ([`$densify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/densify/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-densify)) by creating new documents in a sequence of documents where certain values for a `field` (in our case `field: "ranking"`) are missing:

  - the step for our densification is 1: `range: { step: 1, ... }` since our buckets are following each other with a size of 1.
  - and we densify within the range `[0, 12]`: `bounds: [0, 12]`
- finally sets (`$set`) `count` to `0` only for new documents included during the densify stage (`{ count: { $cond: [ { $not: ["$count"] }, 0, "$count" ] } }`)

---

Note that I'm assuming your buckets are of equal size (assuming the missing 10 in your list is an oversight).